# NGNIX redirect_uri with AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-cognito, nginx-reverse-proxy, apache-superset

I have a service(Apache Superset) running on localhost:8088. I am trying to connect to AWS Cognito using NGINX as a webserver.

My NGINX config is `/etc/ngnix/conf.d/superset.conf`

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name in.welcome.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
        server_name in.welcome.com;
        location / {
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass              http://localhost:8088;
        proxy_read_timeout  90;
        proxy_redirect https://in.welcome.com http://localhost:8088;
        }
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/in.welcome.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/in.welcome.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

With this configuration it is passing the following query string parameters:

```
    DEBUG:authlib.integrations.base_client.base_app:Saving authorize data: 
    {'redirect_uri': 'http://in.welcome.com/oauth-authorized/cognito', 
     'url': 'https://mydomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize? 
     response_type=code&client_id=12345&
     redirect_uri=http://in.welcome.com/oauthauthorized/Fcognito&scope=email+openid+profile&state=1234',
     'state': '1234'}
```

Cognito requires an HTTPS URI, however my this configuration is sending:

```
'redirect_uri': 'http://in.welcome.com/oauth-authorized/cognito
```

Instead of:

```
'redirect_uri': 'https://in.welcome.com/oauth-authorized/cognito
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update superset_config.py with:

```
# Use all X-Forwarded headers when ENABLE_PROXY_FIX is True.
# When proxying to a different port, set "x_port" to 0 to avoid downstream issues. 
ENABLE_PROXY_FIX = True
```